# Expanding JS Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, framer-motion

I'm currently learning Framer Motion in order to create an onClick animation. However, I'm not overly familiar with JS arrow functions. In order to understand the example provided by Framer Motion, I attempted to expand the notation. But I honestly have no idea what the following line is expanded: `onClick={() => setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)}`. The line is this in full context:

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

const variants = {
  open: { opacity: 1, x: 0 },
  closed: { opacity: 0, x: "-100%" },
}

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <motion.nav
      animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
      variants={variants}
    >
      <Toggle onClick={() => setIsOpen(isOpen => !isOpen)} />
      <Items />
    </motion.nav>
  )
}
```

How would this be expanded into standard JS notation/syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by "expand"? Arrow function is standard JS. It is just a function without its own `this`. Curly brackets enclosing the function body of an arrow function can be omitted if the body is a single expression.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's better to try to understand [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) *as they are*, instead of "translating" it into something you already understand.

Having said that, the given expression can be "expanded" into:

```
onClick={
  function () {
    return setIsOpen(function (isOpen) {
      return !isOpen;
    });
  }
}
```